# new added element in the top of JList is automatically selected

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I am creating a JList using swing, I can display and select multiple items, also I can add a new element to it. However, when I select the first element of the list and add a new one to the top, I got two selected elements (the old one and the new one), but when I change the *selection mode to single selection* it works fine, is it possible to prevent this automatic selection and just **keep the old one selected** using *multiple interval selection mode*?
I used this [link](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/UsingListDataListenertolistentoListModelEvents.htm) that contain an example using **DataEventListner** but I did not succeed to find a solution. Any help please?
Here is my list:

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {
    String labels[] = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H" };
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Selecting JList");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    final DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
    for (int i = 0, n = labels.length; i < n; i++) {
        model.addElement(labels[i]);
    }
    JList jlist = new JList(model);
    jlist.setSelectionMode(
            ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
    JScrollPane scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(jlist);
    frame.add(scrollPane1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    JButton jb = new JButton("add F");
    jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            model.add(0, "First");
        }
    });
    frame.add(jb,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.setSize(640, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you basically copied the code in the [link](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/UsingListDataListenertolistentoListModelEvents.htm) in your question. That example only deals with adding a single element to the `JList` when clicking the `JButton`. It does not deal with the `JList` selection[s]. I don't think the author of that example considered what happens when the user selects one or more elements in the `JList` **before** clicking the `JButton`.

I was able to reproduce the behavior described in your question. It may be a bug in the implementation of `JList` or `ListSelectionModel`. The way I fixed it is to add code to method `actionPerformed()` that handles any existing `JList` selections.

Here is my modified version of method `actionPerformed()`. Note that all the rest of the code is unchanged. First I save the indexes of all the selected rows. Then I clear the existing selections. Then I add the new element to the `JList`. Now I need to re-select the rows that were selected before I added the new element. But note that I need to increment each index by one, because there is a new element at index 0 (zero).

```java
jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        int[] indices = jlist.getSelectedIndices();
        jlist.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
        model.add(0, "First");
        for (int index : indices) {
            jlist.getSelectionModel().addSelectionInterval(index + 1, index + 1);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Simple hack that should do the job

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of [JList#setSelectionMode(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setSelectionMode(int)):

> ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION - Only one list index can be
>   selected at a time. In this mode, setSelectionInterval and
>   addSelectionInterval are equivalent, both replacing the current
>   selection with the index represented by the second argument (the
>   "lead").

try `jlist.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);`

Comment: I want to use multiple selections

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any essential information and constrains.

Comment: I guess you missed this part of the original question: _I can display and select multiple items_

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in your jb.addActionListner():

```
int x = jlist.getSelectedIndex();
    jlist.clearSelection();
    jlist.setSelectedIndex(x);
```

This should work just the way you want it to!

Comment: I think this will select the new element, but I want to keep only the old selected values.

Comment: Then you can get the index of the selected item :

Comment: int x = jlist.getSelectedIndex();
        jlist.clearSelection();
        jlist.setSelectedIndex(x);

Comment: What happens if the user selects more than one row in the `JList` **before** he clicks the `JButton`?